# how to align a nested div to the right side of the containing div

Tags: jquery, html, css

I need the whole block of the nested div body aligned to the right border of the containing div? Using css or jquery both cool.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you tried this? `{ float:right }` ?

Answer (score 8):

If you'd like to have it retain block display and static position:

```
.inner { width: ##px, margin-left: auto; margin-right: 0 }
```

Answer (score 5):

CSS

```
.div1 { overflow: hidden; width: 500px; } /* this will clear your float. width given for example purposes */
.div2 { float: right; width: 200px; }
```

HTML

```
<div class="div1">
  <div class="div2">
    <p>div 2 contents</p>
  </div>
  <p>div 1 contents</p>
</div>
```